# Warning: Can't call setState on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, antd

I made a todolist with **react redux**, but I don’t know where the problem is. I would like to ask you to help me check the problem. I’m very grateful.
When the page is refreshed for the first time, the change event is triggered, and there will be a warning. If the second input is not refreshed, there will be no warning. Request a solution

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uvRK.png)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Input, Button, List } from "antd";
import store from "./store";

class TodoList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = store.getState();
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleStoreChange = this.handleStoreChange.bind(this);
    store.subscribe(this.handleStoreChange);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ marginTop: "10px" }}>
        <div>
          <Input
            value={this.state.inputValue}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            placeholder="todolist use antd design"
            style={{ width: "300px", marginRight: "5px" }}
          />
          <Button type="primary" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
            Submit
          </Button>
        </div>
        <List
          style={{ marginTop: "10px", width: "300px" }}
          bordered
          dataSource={this.state.list}
          renderItem={(item) => <List.Item>{item}</List.Item>}
        ></List>
      </div>
    );
  }

  handleInputChange(e) {
    const action = {
      type: "change_input_value",
      value: e.target.value,
    };
    store.dispatch(action);
  }

  handleStoreChange() {
    this.setState(store.getState());
    console.log("store changed");
  }
  handleSubmit() {
    const action = {
      type: "add_todo_item",
    };
    store.dispatch(action);
  }
}

export default TodoList;

// here store folder
// store/index.js
    import { createStore } from "redux";
import reducer from "./reducer";

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

export default store;

// here store/reducer.js
 


 const defaultState = {
  inputValue: "",
  list: [],
};


const reducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  if (action.type === "change_input_value") {
    const newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state)); // 深拷贝一个state
    newState.inputValue = action.value;
    return newState;
  }
  if (action.type === "add_todo_item") {
    const newState = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
    newState.list.push(newState.inputValue);
    newState.inputValue = "";
    return newState;
  }
  console.log(state, action);
  return state;
};

export default reducer;
```

**I doubt it is the version of react or redux. I don’t know what caused the problem.**

[TodoList.js part-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uvRK.png)

[TodoList.js part-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZJYU.png)

[reducer.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWZ24.png)

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEp9j.png)

Comment: try to add all your constructor code inside the componentDidMount hook. example:
componentDidMount() {
 ... your constructor code
}.

Especially the subscribtion one.

Comment: oh man! it works, very thanks.

Comment: `this.setState(store.getState());` is effectively forking the store state into your component state, which is likely not what you want to do...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to put your constructor codes inside componentDidMount hook. Especially the subscription one

```
componentDidMount() { ... your constructor code }
```